# How do I change scenes with JavaScript on click? (Unity5)

Tags: javascript, scene, unity-game-engine

I just want to know how to change to a different scene in Javascript when I click the mouse.
    'Application.LoadLevel' is apparently now obsolete.
Please as simple a script as possible because I really can't grasp the advanced stuff and they usually end up with some sort of error that I'll have to ask about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs cover this quite well.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html

```
Use SceneManager.LoadScene
```

Comment: apparently 'the name scene manager does not exist in the current context' how is that fixed?

Comment: @BrookDaCow Ahh, I see what happened.  "NOTE: This feature is not shipping in Unity 5.0 but we are working on it for a later release" http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/08/04/multi-scene-editing/  What specific version of Unity are you using?

Comment: What could I use to change scenes in the current version?

Comment: It should be in 5.3, try `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement` Looks like that's where it should be located.  And here's the docs http://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html

Comment: hm, that seems to have worked, the error's gone, although when I try to add the script as a component it says 'cannot add script component because the script class cannot be found'. Is this a problem or am i being stupid and shouldn't have added it as a component?

Comment: using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void Example()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Main World");
        }
    }

Comment: Installing 5.3 so I can poke at this myself.  Its taking forever. :V

Comment: Thank you Draco, you really are going above and beyond for this problem

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with Visual Studio.

Comment: And...uninstalling everything and reinstalling (skipping Visual Studio) has left me with a [gray screen](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1091794/gray-screen-when-trying-to-open-unity.html) that a number of users are getting.  Trying another machine, but it's not very fast.

Comment: Nope, gray screen there too.  [Check this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cant-add-component-because-it-doesnt-exist.251746/) and make sure any of the things there (such as the class name and filename matching exactly, including Case) as well as the console for any compiler errors.

Comment: Thank you Draco, I think the information you provided coupled with the links you posted has answered my question.

Comment: Oh good!  Now I just have to pester Unity to fix 5.3 :D (or I could say "fox it" and keep using 5.1).  Glad I could help solve the ancillary problems that cropped up.

Answer (score 0):

In javaScript, it's a bit indirect but not hard

```
//first you need to declare the class file for SceneManager

var ls:UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager;

//then after declaring this, you can use the LoadScene function

function Start () {

         ls.LoadScene("menu"); 
}
```